# Question about SP-API and access to seller accounts

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api, amazonsellercentral

I've been beating my head against the brick wall of Amazon "documentation" for a few weeks now and thought I had what I needed.

I setup the IAM user in our AWS account, created a developer account for seller central, went through their insane vetting process just to get that dev account setup, and now that I have it I can make requests but of course get no data because my account is just a developer account and has no products or orders to load for testing.

The situation is that I'm a developer working for a company that has multiple seller central stores. I've been tasked with doing an integration with SP-API to sync inventory and pricing, pull in new orders for fulfillment, the whole deal.

So what I have now is a seller central developer account and an app in that account but can't pull any data from our company stores. The apps are supposed to be private but at the moment it seems like my only option is to make it public. Is that the case or am I missing something?

Should I have instead asked whoever the "primary user" is of our seller central stores to create the app clients? If so, what is the point of the developer account in the case of private apps??

Just really frustrated here and can't find any info to help me understand just what I need to do from here.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide!

Answer (score 0):

Amazon does not currently have a development environment for creating apps. You need to build the app in the actual Seller Central account that you will be interacting with. See this link: https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/registering-your-application

> For the purposes of registering your application, applications are grouped into two types:
> **All public applications and private seller applications**. These are: (1) Applications that are publicly available and are authorized by a seller or by a vendor, and (2) seller applications that are available only to your organization, and are self-authorized.
> **Private vendor applications**. Vendor applications that are available only to your organization, and are self-authorized.

Figure out which category you fit under and proceed as directed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to register for a public application. Then you can invite your store owners / sellers to provide auth to your application. In this way you will be able pull order or others data via sp api in terms of the sellers.

Comment: Is there any API available for getting current self authorized seller profile using oAuth code, access-token, refresh-token or sellerId?